# Why can't multiple animations run together?

Tags: java, multithreading, animation

I have two buffered images. One is a buffered image that is controlled by the user with the arrow keys and starts animating it's legs when the user presses the arrow keys. The second buffered image is like the enemy in the game they move autonomously and their animation starts right away. When I run these two images at once, only one will do their own animation. Why can't both animations run together?
Here is with the code (sorry if it's a bit long. these are the two update methods for the animation):

```
public void update()
{
    if(walking)
    {
        for(int frame=0;frame<(Art.player.length+1);frame++)
        {
            try{
                currentFrame=Art.player[frame][0];
                Timer timer = new Timer(5,this);
                timer.start();
                repaint();
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                frame=0;
                currentFrame=Art.player[frame][0];
                Timer timer = new Timer(5,this);
                timer.start();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}
public void enemyUpdate()
{
    if(inView)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<(Art.enemy.length+1);j++)
        {
            try{
                currentFrameEnemy=Art.enemy[j][0];
                enemyX++;
                enemyY++;
                if(enemyX>=800||enemyY>=600)
                {
                    enemyX=0;
                    enemyY=0;
                }
                Timer timer = new Timer(5,this);
                timer.start();
                repaint();
            }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                j=0;
                currentFrameEnemy=Art.enemy[j][0];
                enemyX++;
                enemyY++;
                if(enemyX>=800||enemyY>=600)
                {
                    enemyX=0;
                    enemyY=0;
                }
                Timer timer = new Timer(5,this);
                timer.start();
                repaint();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: they can. show us the code

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot-link to some small (in bytes) images or generate them in code.

Comment: This if your 5th posting on this topic. The code you have posted doesn't help! You have been asked before to post a SSCCE. A SSCCE is not about your program, it is about proving a simple concept. So first create a simple example that has two images each controlled by a separate time. Once you get the simple concept working you move on to something more complex.

Comment: well this is not the same topic. I was posting a lot before about key bindings and couldn't think of any titles, so I always put animation in it. If you read the problems before you would have realized this is with Threads and the other with Key bindings.

Comment: All the topics are related and yet you spend time with an unnecessary comment instead of posting a proper SSCCE so you can get some proper help! And if you think this is a different question then the ones on the key bindings, then why haven't you accepted any answers from those questions?

Comment: because I found my own solution. None of those I tried worked.

Comment: meh...might as well not use stack if this is what keeps happening then. I clearly don't want to do anything with an SSCCE, so I will just figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean none of them worked? I gave you working code. All you had to do was use the concepts I showed you. Of course the code we post is not going to be exactly what you need because we are not going to write the code for you. It is the concept that is important to understand. And the concept to solve you problem is to use key bindings. A SSCCE is a tool to help you simplify the problem and better understand what you are doing. Your approach to problem solving doesn't appear to be working. Why not try something else. Why do you think we keep suggesting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using different threads on each animation.

Comment: currently i am just running two Thread.sleep() in each entities update method for the animation. does that count as using different threads or is that just using the same thread. I also never initiated an actual thread I just call Thread.sleep().

Comment: @user1058860 with `Thread.sleep()` you are telling your UI-thread to sleep

Comment: what does that mean I should do then? I am new to concurrent programming.

Comment: @user1058860 use a Timer to run code at predictable intervals. `javax.swing.Timer` if using swing, `java.util.Timer` otherwise.

Comment: well i tried replacing the two threads in the code with the Timer. I used in both methods a Timer(5,this) after it got the currentFrame to update. It still only ran one of the animations and the other image would just stand still.

Comment: Who knows what you did with those Timers. You should have posted that code instead.

Comment: alright I edited the post to show where I put the timers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate Animation class which loads the set of images and runs their animations, try implementing Runnable, and refactoring your animation methods `public void update()` and `public void enemyUpdate()` inside the `public void run()` method that comes from Runnable interface. After that is done, if you run the `.start()` method of your two separate, refactored animation objects, they'll be animated concurrently.

Otherwise, if you have all your animations started from some main loop and they run one after another (that is, not concurrently), some delay might be noticeable based on how many Animation objects you got running. Basically each separate animation object needs to be run in its own thread if you want them to be run as much in parallel as your hardware will allow.

Comment: alright I will try that out!

Comment: where should I call the .start() method?

Comment: Somewhere from your main. You'd probably want the class with your main function to be a thread as well, since that would allow you to specify a constant frame-rate. Here's an example, note, my main class implements 'Runnable()' as well.

Comment: <code>     public void run() {
        Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
        while (current == gameloop) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            /*Draw all of the sprites in the arrayList to the backbuffer */            
            repaint();  //draw to the screen
    }
} </code>

Comment: So `repaint()` would call `paint()`. In `paint()`, you need to implement double-buffering, and somewhere there, call your animations.     `public void paint(Graphics g){
        /*Get the Graphics object on which to draw on */

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;/*Now lets draw the backbuffer INTO the screen */
        try {
        /*Draw whatever we need to onto the backbuffer first */
        instance.paintToBackbuffer();
        g2d.drawImage(doubleBuffer, null , 0, 0);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

Comment: Finally, in `paintToBackbuffer()` method, you would call another method (e.g. `drawAllSprites()`) where your animations start/are drawn.     `private void paintToBackbuffer(){
         /* The backbuffered version */
        instance.doubleBufferG2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        instance.doubleBufferG2D.fillRect(0, 0, instance.WIDTH, instance.HEIGHT);
        instance.doubleBufferG2D.setColor(Color.red);

        this.drawAllSprites();
    }` At least thats how I set it up.